# Home Assistant expecting a string: Got none

Tags: home-automation

I'm creating a radio station in Home Assistant. Get an script error but don't understand what the error gives.

`Invalid config for [script]: template value should be a string for dictionary value @ data['sequence'][1]['data']. Got None.`

script file:

```
# Radio play script
radio_play:
  alias: 'Speel Radio'
  sequence:
    - service: media_player.volume_set
    - data: 
        entity_id: >
          {%if is_state("input_select.radio_speaker", "Soundbar") %} media_player.soundbar
          {%elseif is_state("input_select.radio_speaker", "Other Speaker") %} media_player.other_speaker
          {% endif %}
        volume_level: '{{ states("input_number.radio_volume")}}'
    - service: media_player.play_media
      data: 
        entity_id: >
          {%if is_state("input_select.radio_speaker", "Soundbar") %} media_player.soundbar
          {%elseif is_state("input_select.radio_speaker", "Other Speaker") %} media_player.other_speaker
          {% endif %}
        media_content_id: >
          {% if is_state("input_select.radio_station", "Radio 10") %} https://21633.live.streamtheworld.com/RADIO10.mp3
          {% elseif is_state("input_select.radio_station", "Sublime") %} https://20873.live.streamtheworld.com/SUBLIME.mp3
          {% endif %}
        media_content_type: 'music'
```

There are two separate files which create the input fields. That doesn't seem to create the "error"

Can anyone spot what is happening?

Comment: there is a difference between `none` and `None` ... in some programming languages, `None` is a keyword, and usually means Null value or an empty set of objects.... for example, think of a function that returns information about fruit in a bowl ... when asked to return a list of fruit, of type "apple", `None` could be returned if there are no apples in the bowl